# Rewriting query string using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In my MVC application I use a uri router than determines which controller and action to use and detects GET parameters from the uri. I've written it so that it will accept both these forms:

```
http://localhost/controller/action/param1Name/param1Value
http://localhost/controller/action?param1Name=param1Value
```

Now what I'd like to do is use mod_rewrite to redirect the `?p=v` form to the `/p/v` form (reasoning is purely cosmetic, GET forms use the `?x=y` form). I'm completely stuck with how I'd do this however - I have an idea I need to use `${QUERY_STRING}` but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to redirect requests of the form `/controller/action?param1Name=param1Value` to `/controller/action/param1Name/param1Value`, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^/]+/[^/]+\?[^\s]+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=&]+)=([^&]+)&?(.*)
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+.* /$0/%1/%2?%3 [N]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^/]+/[^/]+\?[^\s]+
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+.* /$0 [L,R=301]
```

But if you want to opposite way:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*) $1$4?$2=$3 [QSA]
```

Comment: That's some crazy regex-fu :) It doesn't seem to work for me though - the GET params in the url stay as they are.

Comment: It still doesn't want to work on my platform but if it's working for you I'll mark it as answered. I decided to change where I use a form into some hyperlinks anyway). Thanks

Comment: You might want to use mod_rewrite’s logging function to see where it breaks. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it for cosmetic reasons you may want to do a POST instead, and then the query params will not be shown in the URL.

If not - I'd like to see the answer to this one myself!

Comment: If it can't be done then yeah I'll take this approach. Would still be nice if it's possible though.