# redirect with .htaccess and get parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Can anybody help me?

I need to redirect request with get parameters like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/listings/?tx_listingcontroller[countryId]=4&tx_listingcontroller[regionId]=2868&cHash=f59c2ae1b037df6fc8a1e2a55ea0ee96
```

to

```
http://www.mynewsite.com/listings/countryId/4/regionId/2868/cHash/f59c2ae1b037df6fc8a1e2a55ea0ee96
```

Anybody know how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179868/rewriting-query-string-using-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 1):

You can add a RewriteRule to your .htaccess file.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html.  This uses RegEx to parse the incoming URL and redirect to a new URL based on the matched segments.  Something like...

`RewriteRule ^listings/?tx_listingcontroller[countryId]=(.*)&tx_listingcontroller[regionId]=(.*)&cHash=(.*)$ listings/countryId/$1/regionId/$2/cHash/$3`