# wordpress permalink after $_GET form

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress plugin with this form:

```
<form method="get"> 
<input name="something" type="text">
<input type="submit" name="sendValue" value="send">
</form>
```

If i enter the text "myText" and press the button, i will go to something like this:

"mysite.com/the-page/?send=sendValue&something=mytext"

Is there a way to change this to a structure like this:

"mysite.com/the-page/send/sendValue/something/mytext

However, i still want to be able to get the data using $_GET

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewriting query string using mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179868/rewriting-query-string-using-mod-rewrite)

Comment: See `WP_Rewrite` in Wordpress [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite). More specifically `generate_rewrite_rule()`